# First visit to codeigniter site is redirected to root

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have inherited a codebase using CodeIgniter.

When fist viewing the site, all pages are redirected to the homepage. After that, the site works as normal.

If I create a "real page" outside of codeigniter, there is no redirection. This rules out htaccess issues.

The routes.php contains:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['404_override'] = 'Error_new';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

The Controller Homes.php

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('pagination_helper');
        no_cache();
        $this->load->helper(array('form'));
        $this->load->helper(array('cookie', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('home_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        /*redirect(base_url().'booking');*/
        $this->load->library('Mobile_Detect');
        $detect = new Mobile_Detect();

        if ($detect->isTablet()) {
             //$this->home_model->insert_city_in_tbl();
            $template['page'] = 'Home/home';
           $template['page_title'] = "xxxxx";
            $this->load->view('template', $template);

        } 

       else if ($detect->isMobile()  || $detect->isAndroidOS()) {
             redirect('https://m.xxxx.com/');


        } else {

            //$this->home_model->insert_city_in_tbl();
            $template['page'] = 'Home/home';
            $template['logo'] = get_settings_details(1, null);
            $template['country'] = get_settings_details(null, 'country');
            $template['popular_routes']=$this->home_model->getPopularRoutes();
            $template['page_title'] = "XXXXXXX";
            $this->load->view('template', $template);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any pointers on how to solve this?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that there's something wrong on your mobile detection logic. You seem to be directing almost everyone once to `home/home` after mobile detection. (exceptions being those who are redirected to `m.example.com` because they are flagged as mobile or android

Comment: Its not this as the redirect happens before index function is called. Also, this doesnt explain first time visitors only

Comment: Well it might. Since your default controller is `home` the very first thing that is called is `home/index` which runs the mobile detection routine. Without seeing that code it's only possible to guess, but there could be some cookies involved preventing non-first timers to be re-validated and redirected.

Comment: but then again, I'm just guessing. I don't know the library you're using and looking it up on my phone is the least readable thing that I could do... what have you tried to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to do with some cookies logic redirect customers to homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Change your live config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.yoursite.com
```

[Source](https://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-66250.html)